# How do I create a blank blazor project on Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I am trying to create a blazor project on visual studio, because I have a LOT of C# code I could recycle, but I have never used blazor before and therefore have little experience to know what on the default-generated samples (which include weather forecasting and a side nav bar I still haven't figured out how to delete) is completely useless to my purposes and should be deleted.
As such, I'd like to create a blank website. However, VS will not allow me to do so.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: If you are new to Blazor then it's best to start with one of the default templates.  You can then modify it and save it as a [custom project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022) for reuse.

Comment: [Polite] Do you know how to write `App.razor` and a `LayoutBase`?  If you've never used Blazor before, then unlikely.  So you will get a blank Blazor project with little idea of how to get started.  If you don't know how to remove the existing content, then how are you going to built new?